# Surprisingly large filesize for simple Flex Applications

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I just recently downloaded the trial version of **Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP** from Adobe.

I created a couple of very simple projects just to get the gist of this new software and was quite optimistic about all of it.

But the last 3 projects (by projects I mean just simple one-state screens really) are now really slow to download and that is due to the fact that now users are required to download 2MB (!!) worth of data for real simple stuff!

I was thinking that I was doing something wrong but, when I created this project whose code I'm about to show, and Firebug told me that **2MB** is being downloaded everytime I open the app I think there's something really wrong going on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="400" height="400" minWidth="400" minHeight="400">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Panel x="50" y="41" width="301" height="286">
        <s:Label x="96" y="81" fontSize="15" text="Really pissed off"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

**That's it. One panel and one label.** Before it was virtually instant. Now users have to download 2MB worth of data to visualize just this.

**What's going on here guys?**

P.S.: I know about RSL's but what I don't get is how I was able to make apps like this in this very same IDE (FB 4.5) and now whenever I make even simple apps like the one shown above I get ridiculous waiting/loading times. That's totally prohibitive. I'm thinking about switching back to Flex Builder 3.

Comment: The file size is for the debug or release version?

Comment: Bin-debug version. Is the size reduction so dramatic from the bin-debug version to the bin-release version?

Comment: Sometimes it is. Can you post the swf file?

Comment: I have a debug version that is 2.5MB and a release version that is 700k

Comment: The mx packages add a lot of overhead in my opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using the debug version of the swf. To reduce the size try to remove the swc that are not reqd. in you project like osmf, textLayout etc.

Comment: When compiling a SWF the Flex Compiler should automatically remove all classes that are not used; so removing SWCs should have no affect on SWF file size.  If you set the framework to be an RSL; then Adobe libraries (such as for TLF or OSMF ) aren't even compiled into the SWF at all.